# Accessing react-navigation props when wrapping in HOC (binding this)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm rather new to React Native, React Navigation, and HOCs.  I'm trying to use the `react-native-responsive-ui` HOC alongside `react-navigation`.  For normal components, I can do something like this:

```
export default class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Settings',
    headerRight: <Button onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen')} title="Btn" />
  }
  ...
}
```

However, I've found that, if I'm wrapping my component with the `responsive` HOC, defining navigationOptions in my component has no effect.  I have to define them on the wrapped component instead:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component { ... }

const ResponsiveHomeScreen = responsive(HomeScreen)
ResponsiveHomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Home',
  headerRight: <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen')} title="Btn" />
}
export default ResponsiveHomeScreen
```

This gets everything displaying properly, but clicking the button crashes:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.props.navigation')
```

Clearly, "this" is not bound in my wrapped component.  I'm just not sure how to get it bound, or if I'm approaching this wrong and there's another way that I'm missing.  Thoughts?

Comment: Don't use `this` then. `navigationOptions` can also be a function, and it's first argument is `navigation`. No need for `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Li357's comment has the solution.  I simply rewrote `navigationOptions` as a function, as per [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title):

```
const ResponsiveHomeScreen = responsive(HomeScreen)
ResponsiveHomeScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    title: 'FlashNote',
    headerRight: <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen')} title="Btn" />
  }
}
```

Voila, problem solved.  Thanks, Li357!